# Area in 2 dimensions

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

I tried to solve for the area of below shape and convinced that we need more information. Is there a way to solve without needing extra information?

My approach is to calculate the area of the rectangle first, and then subtracting areas of 3 triangles from it. However, we need the width of the rectangle (the length being 38.2cm),

[image]

Comment: Is that all the information you get?  Unless you can assume that the shape is made up of two parallelograms, you do not have enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Use an obvious shearing, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping, to transform the figure in a rectangle of width 3.8 and height 38.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you cut in the middle horizontally and recombine two pieces together, then you will have a parallelogram, right? Then, the area is simply base times height. The base for that is two times 3.8 cm, the height is 19.1 cm.

Comment: Well, the diagram as shown doesn't make this explicit.  What if the center joint has width different from $3.8$ cm?

Comment: that is true, in that case, I think the question needs that width difference specified

Comment: @Brian Tung "What if the center joint has width different from 3.8 cm" : do you imagine for a second a crooked/vicious/perverse instructor giving this exercise and saying afterwards to his student : in fact you should have measured the center joint which is 3.81 cm, not 3.80 ? :):):)

Comment: @JeanMarie: You mistake my meaning.  We are given no additional information by OP.  It is entirely plausible that this is a multiple choice question where one of the options is "Not enough information to determine."  It is quite common on standardized tests.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Look, you don't want to believe it, be my guest.

Comment: I fully understand